# Return Default jSon Data With Property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am converting data from database into **jSon** as following with `ASP.NET Web Api`:

```
public string GetData(string userId)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    };

    string Query = "select USER_ID UserId, USER_NAME UserName from Table where USER_ID = '" + userId + "'";
    DataTable dt = SelectData(Query);

    string jSonResult;
    jSonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, settings);

    return jSonResult;
}
```

In the project's web api config file, it has the following setting:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST");
      config.EnableCors(cors);

     //Web api routes
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
      
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
     GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

}
```

It returns me the expected **jSon** data but the issue is the data returned with properties turns into uppercase as follows:

```
[
  {
    "USERID": "1002",
    "USERNAME": "John"
   
  }
]
```

Though I used a formatter to keep it default but it returns the above. Any way I can return the properties as below:

```
[
  {
    "UserId": "1002",
    "UserName": "John"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `JsonSerializerSettings` replace the  `ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()`
into
`ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()`

for example

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
```

Comment: Add column name to the Datatable like this
`dt.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));`

Comment: It worked but I had to make few changes later. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static string GetData(string userId)
        {

             

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("UserID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("UserName", typeof(string));
            
            //Some dummy data
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Townsend");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Marget");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Deva");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Aurthur");

            
             
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
                
            };


            string jSonResult;
            jSonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);


            return jSonResult;


        }
```

It will return the following result

```
[
  {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "Townsend"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 2,
    "UserName": "Marget"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 3,
    "UserName": "Deva"
  },
  {
    "UserID": 4,
    "UserName": "Aurthur"
  }
]
```